# Table or lists?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I've posted about this question a couple times, and I've figured out the problem with the formatting I was getting, but I want to reevaluate the situation (jumped in too deeply too soon I think) and hopefully get a better answer.

It is working okay now, picture below, but I'd like to know best practices, and perhaps get it to be lined up more precisely.

[image]

So the table-looking thing below is two lists. Actually, three lists including the one hack to get "agree" and "disagree" on top.

But something about that strikes me as a little campy. Not that great. An on-the-go patchwork solution.

How would you guys do this, so that ng-repeat can dynamically generate a list containing a different number of user comparisons at different times?

Here's my code:

```js
$scope.profileCompare = {

        You: {
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, false, false],
            percent: ['0%', '20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Unimportant",
            match: "30%"
        },
        Pizza: {
            questionAnswer: [false, true, true, false, false, false],
            percent: ['0%', '20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Important",
            match: "30%"
        },
        Greenie: {
            questionAnswer: [false, true, false, false, true, false],
            percent: ['0%', '20%', '40%', '60%', '80%', '100%'],
            questionImportance: "Very Important",
            match: "40%"
        }
    }
```

```css
.result1 {
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
    position:relative;
    left: 10px;

}

.result1 ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 1em;
    width: .4em;
    text-align: right;
    font-size:1em;
    position:relative;
    right:25px;
}

.result {
    float: left;
}

.result ul li{
    display: inline-block;
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 1em;
    width: .4em;
    text-align: right;
    font-size:1em;
    position:relative;
    right:25px;
}
```

```html
<div class="comparisons">
 <p>{{question}}</p>
  <br>
  <div class="comparisons-background">
   <a href="#/cl-background">
    go to background
   </a>
  </div>
</div>



<div>

  <div class="result1"style="display:inline; margin:0 auto">
    <div><br><br><br>
    </div>
    <div ng-repeat="(key, profile) in profileCompare">
      <p>{{key}}:</p>
      <p style="font-size:80%">{{profile.questionImportance}},</p>
      <p style="font-size:90%; font-weight: bold"> {{profile.match}} match </p>
      <br>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="result" style="display:inline">
    <ul>
      <li>Agree</li><li></li><li></li><li></li><li>Disagree</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-repeat="(key, profile) in profileCompare">
      <div class="result">
      <ul>
          <li ng-repeat="answer in profile.questionAnswer track by $index"><i class="fa" ng-class="{green:answer, red:!answer, 'fa-check-square':answer, 'fa-square':!answer}"></i></li>
          <br><br>
      </ul>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Best practice in this case is to turn the inner ng-repeat into a directive instead.

Comment: Ar hm. Can you provide any pointers for that?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive AND this http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html

Comment: Question is a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ since there is no specific problem or question

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about that.

Answer (score 0):

A more semantically-correct solution would be to position the Agree/Disagree labels with CSS instead of jamming meaningless `<li>`s between them. You could do that by `float`ing them `left` and `right`, or using `absolute` `position`ing.

Also, `<ol>` would technically be more correct than `<ul>`, since the ratings *are* ordered.

P.S. Shouldn't the checkboxes be radios?

Comment: Radios? Dunno -- they don't need to be checked, so this seems to work well enough

Comment: But, how would I sync up the two lists. As it is right now, they just incidentally align with each other - but is there a way to dictate that that is what should happen?